# CLT for sum of products of Gaussian variables

Tags: central-limit-theorem, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have two multivariate Gaussians $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \Sigma_x^2)$ and $\mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_y, \Sigma_y^2)$. I assume that the covariances are diagonal.

I am interested in modelling the distribution of their product $a = \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}$, ideally as another Gaussian. Since it is a sum of products and can be rewritten as $a = \sum_i x_iy_i$.

Does the central limit theorem hold in this case?

Comment: Are the two multivariate Gaussians independent?